# Python check if all elements in a list are Nan

Tags: python, numpy, nan

My code sometimes produces a list of nan's `op_list = [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]`.
I want to know if all elements are nans.

My code and present output:

```
  op_list = [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
  print(np.isnan(op_list))
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True])
```

My expected output:

```
   True
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need `all`:

```
np.isnan(op_list).all()
# True
```

For a solution using lists you can do:

```
all(i != i for i in op_list)
# True
```